# Dos formas de hacer una consulta en fastAPI ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

En la documentación de fastAPI ocupan esta manera:

```py
def get_one_country(db: Session, code: str):
    return db.query(models.Country).filter(models.Country.Code == code).first()
```

Pero en guías que he visto ocupan esta otra:

```py
def get_one_country(ID: str):
    result = conn.execute(world_x.select().where(world_x.c.ID == ID)).first()
```

- ¿ Existe alguna diferencia en entre ellas? y si existe ¿Cuál es?

Comment: ¿Más eficiente en cuanto a...? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @OCHOA Ten cuidado cuando editas código de Python, ya que la indentación es crítica. Si vas a editar código, agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo.

Comment: @padaleiana fue sin querer. Lo tendré muy en cuenta. Gracias

Comment: @padaleiana Supongo que en vez de eficiencia tendria que usar la frase "mas recomendado". Veo que en tutoriales de youtube usan la segunda forma pero en la documentacion(tutorial) de fastapi usan la primera.

Comment: No preguntes por recomendaciones, ya que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera versión hace uso de un ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) que es un mecanismo para evitarte tener que escribir código de bajo nivel para acceder a la base de datos. Un ORM te "mapea" (convierte) las tablas de la base de datos en objetos de tu lenguaje de programación (en este caso Python). Una vez el ORM ha obtenido los datos deseados de la BD, crea con ellos un objeto y eso es lo que te retorna.

La segunda forma no hace uso de ORM. La consulta es SQL más directa y el valor retornado es un objeto que representa una fila de la tabla de la base de datos, en lugar de ser un objeto de tu dominio de aplicación.

Un ejemplo puede aclarar las cosas. Dado que el ejemplo que propones usa paises, supongamos que tu base de datos tiene dos tablas: una con los paises (para cada país su ID, su nombre y su "code") y otra con ciudades (para cada ciudad tendrá su ID, su nombre, y el ID del país al que pertenece, lo cual es una clave foránea en esa tabla).

Usando el primer enfoque deberás antes escribir en Python tu modelo de datos, el cual podría ser tal que así:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Code = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    cities = relationship("City", back_populates="country")

class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('countries.id'))
    country = relationship("Country", back_populates="cities")
```

Ves cómo la tabla de paises da lugar a la clase `Country` y dentro de esa clase se declaran las columnas que tendría la tabla (`id` y `name`), pero también se declaran campos que en realidad no estarán en la base de datos, como el campo `cities`, que representa una relación con la otra tabla y veremos luego cómo se usa.

Análogamente en la tabla de ciudades tenemos tres campos que son verdaderamente columnas de la base de datos (`id`, `name` y `country_id`, ésta última es la clave foránea que relaciona una ciudad con su país) y un campo que no va a la base de datos, llamado `country` que es una forma directa de acceder a los datos del país de una cierta ciudad.

Si ese es el modelo de datos, cuando haces una consulta como ésta:

```
pais = db.query(models.Country).filter(models.Country.Code == code).first()
```

lo que obtendrás como resultado será un objeto de tipo `Country` y por tanto podrás acceder a sus atributos, y así en `pais.name` tendrás el nombre del país. Pero ¡aquí viene una diferencia importante! puedes acceder también al campo "falso" de ciudades: `pais.cities`. A ese campo le digo "falso" porque no existe en la tabla de la base de datos, pero significaría "todas las ciudades pertenecientes a este país". Cuando accedes a ese campo, el ORM hará por tí otra consulta a la base de datos para obtener de la tabla "cities" todas aquellas cuyo `country_id` coincida con el de `pais.id`. Tú no tienes que hacer esta consulta. Ocurre "automágicamente".

Así podrías retornar todos los nombres de las ciudades de un pais con un código como éste:

```
def get_all_country_city_names(db: Session, code: str):
    pais = db.query(models.Country).filter(models.Country.Code == code).first()
    ciudades = [ ciudad.name for ciudad in pais.cities ]
    return ciudades
```

Como ves, el ORM te oculta el SQL necesario para hacer los joins de las tablas y te proporciona en cambio una API en la que manejas objetos como si estuvieran enlazados entre sí a través de sus relaciones.

De la misma forma, cada ciudad obtenida el el bucle anterior tiene un campo `country` que permite acceder a información de su pais, por lo que podrías escribir en tu código `ciudad.country.Code` por ejemplo.

Usando el segundo enfoque en cambio lo que tienes como resultado es una fila de la base de datos, no un objeto de tu modelo. Una vez has obtenido la fila que te interesaba con tu consulta:

```
pais = conn.execute(world_x.select().where(world_x.c.ID == ID)).first()
```

si quisieras obtener el nombre del pais ya no puedes hacer directamente `pais.name` sino que tendrías que hacer algo como `pais[world_x.c.Name]` (la sintaxis concreta depende de cómo hubieras creado la base de datos.

No solo eso, si quisieras la lista de ciudades del país, no tienes acceso directo a ella como antes, sino que tienes que armar una nueva consulta para obtenerla, algo como:

```
ciudades = conn.execute(select([world_x.c.Name, cities_x.c.Name]).
                      select_from(world_x.join(cities_x, world_x.c.ID == cities_x.c.CountryCode)).
                      where(world_x.c.Code == code)).fetchall()
```

en la que tienes que programar explícitamente el JOIN de las dos tablas. Esto te dará como resultado una lista de filas, cada fila conteniendo el nombre del pais y de la ciudad. Podrías acceder al nombre de cada ciudad con un bucle como:

```
for row in ciudades:
    print(row[cities_x.c.Name])
```

### Resumen

La primera forma es una interfaz de alto nivel, orientada a objetos, para trabajar con tus datos. El ORM se ocupa de convertir tus objetos Python a filas de base de datos y viceversa, y de las operaciones SQL necesarias para ello.

La segunda forma es una interfaz de más bajo nivel que te permite operar directamente sobre la base de datos. Te permite tener un control más fino de qué operaciones haces sobre la base de datos, pero también puede ser más engorrosa de usar.

Desde el punto de vista de la legibilidad y facilidad de uso, la primera forma es preferible, pero a veces hay operaciones que no es posible hacer de esa forma (especialmente en bases de datos muy complicadas), o bien el ORM no soporta ciertas opciones de tu base de datos concreta, que podrían hacer las consultas más eficientes. Si necesitas ese acceso a más bajo nivel, deberás usar la segunda.

Desde el punto de vista de la velocidad y eficiencia, todo depende de cómo utilices la segunda opción. Ya que tienes más libertad en ella podrías quizás crear un código más eficiente que el que el ORM haría por tí, pero también es posible que crees un código mucho más ineficiente.

Comment: "Ya que tienes más libertad en ella podrías quizás crear _un código_ más eficiente que el que el ORM haría por ti, pero también es posible que crees un código mucho más ineficiente." Lo que coloqué en cursivas, ¿es realmente así o debería ser _una consulta_?

Comment: Si, bueno, ambas cosas. Para hacer la consulta debes escribir código Python que la ejecute. Según sea ese código (bucles, condiciones) puedes también afectar a la eficiencia